# Grails 3.2.8 upgrade: Implementing filters

Tags: grails

I am working on a Grails upgrade from version 2.4.4 to 3.2.8. I read that Grails 3 introduces interceptors however still supports filters. I think I would like to continue using filters as I have a couple filters that are extensive. Below is a snippet where I basically check what the request is and set variable to be used in the view layout gsp. How can I either continue using the filter I had create (How do I register this filter) or how can I convert the following to an interceptor.

```
class AdminMenuFilters {

    def ACTIVE_CLASS_NAME = "active"

    def filters = {

        admin(controller:'admin', action:'index') {
            before = {
                request.dashboardActive = ACTIVE_CLASS_NAME
            }
        }

        layout(controller:'layout', action:'*'){
            before = {
                def layoutActive = false
                switch(actionName){
                    case null :
                        layoutActive = true
                        break;
                    case "index" :
                        layoutActive = true
                        break;
                    case "tags" :
                        layoutActive = true
                        break;
                    case "how" :
                        layoutActive = true
                        break;
                }
                if(layoutActive){
                    request.layoutActive = ACTIVE_CLASS_NAME
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

See the upgrade docs, there is a filters plugin you can include to continue to use filters. http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/upgrading.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using interceptors as recommended. I will need to create an interceptor for each controller instead of one filter, then use regex to catch when an action is selected and set my active variable.

**Example using layout controller**

```
class LayoutActiveInterceptor{

    LayoutActiveInterceptor(){
        match(controller:"layout", action: ~/(index|tags|how)/)
    }

    boolean before() { 
        request.layoutActive = Constants.ACTIVE_CLASS_NAME
        true 
    }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() {
        // no-op
    }
}
```

Honestly, I think this is a situation where one class file is enough. Any guidance on how to register a filter just in case would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.